# android - Selected image in spinner, when selected, text box appears

Tags: android, arrays, image, textbox, spinner

Below is my code for two working image spinners, using full_battery as the example, what im after is that is there a way that if a certain image is selected, can i get a text box is appear

Any tips or links are appreciated

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

String[] labels={"Full","Half","Low"};
int CauseIcons[] = {full_battery, R.drawable.half_battery, R.drawable.low_battery};
int EffectIcons[] = {R.drawable.wifi_off, R.drawable.bluetooth_off};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner CauseSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CauseSpinner);
    Spinner EffectSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.EffectSpinner);
    CauseSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    EffectSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),CauseIcons,labels);
    CauseSpin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    EffectAdapter customAdapter1=new EffectAdapter(getApplicationContext(),EffectIcons);
    EffectSpin.setAdapter(customAdapter1);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), labels[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(R.drawable.full_battery.******){
       // "textbox".isVisible();

    }



}
```

**Update**:
Alternatively is it possible/ easily to say that when a certain label is selected e.g. if full is selected, then text box appears then just else if not then invisible

**Update 2**:
New attempted version, I thought by defining images in global scope, this would give them variable IDs to use in the if statements, now the problem that, in the if statement in onItemSelected(), the *** part cant resolve symbols .equals(int) or .contains(int) and the app crashes with e.g. selectedImage == (empty)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


    int empty = R.drawable.empty;
    int full = R.drawable.full_battery;
    int half = R.drawable.half_battery;
    int low = R.drawable.low_battery;
    int onLocation = R.drawable.location_on;
    int onBluetooth = R.drawable.bluetooth_on;
    int onWifi = R.drawable.wifi_on;
    int offWifi = R.drawable.wifi_off;
    int offBluetooth = R.drawable.bluetooth_off;
    int offLocation =  R.drawable.location_off;
    int offAlarm = R.drawable.alarm_off;

    Spinner causeSpin;
    EditText causeText;
    int causeIcons[] = {empty, full, half,low, onLocation, onBluetooth, onWifi};

    Spinner effectSpin;
    EditText effectText;
    int effectIcons[] = {empty,offWifi,offBluetooth,offLocation,offAlarm};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //This stops the keyboard automatically appearing on app start up
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        causeSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CauseSpinner);
        causeSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), causeIcons);
        causeSpin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        effectSpin= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.EffectSpinner);
        effectSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        EffectAdapter customAdapter1 = new EffectAdapter(getApplicationContext(), effectIcons);
        effectSpin.setAdapter(customAdapter1);

       causeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.causeTextBox);
       causeText.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //
       effectText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.effectTextBox);
       effectText.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //



    }

//    String text = causeSpin.getSelectedItem().toString();

    int selectedImage = (int)causeSpin.getSelectedItem();
   // getResources().getDrawable(causeIcons[0]);
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView < ? > parentView, View selectedItemView, int  position, long id) {

        if (selectedImage.*******(onLocation)){


        }
```